# Is pip-installing a GitHub PR future-proof?

Tags: python, github, pip

I am in dependency hell right now where we need to use the functionality of library X which is only available if a specific, unmerged PR to library Y is installed. If I add this PR to my requirements, like so:

```
git+https://github.com/org/project.git@refs/pull/123/head
```

will that keep working even after the PR has been merged? And what if the contributor who made the PR removes their branch that was used for the PR?

Comment: Even if the pull request link could be accesed after the pr is merged, you can not be sure that the pull request is not modified. The only way to be safe is clone the repository and point to your own copy

Comment: If you "need" this functionality, you should either merge this ASAP or build from the branch to be merged. Don't make your code depend on GitHub-specific features.

Comment: As far as I know, the head of a pull request like the head of a branch can change over time. I guess if you can find out the commit hash, then you should use this instead.

Comment: @chepner It's a pr to a third party repo that I have no control over.

Comment: Clone it and build it locally. You should not be depending on a PR that, for all you know, could be removed at any time.

Comment: @chepner It is a dependency so needs to go into a project file. But your last point was exactly the question: if a pr is removed (or merged and closed) is it then still available via it's PR url

Comment: but you can still push to a branch after it's been merged. I'm not sure if it will change where your URL is pointing, but it doesn't seem very safe either way.